# Get rid of a video-Element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video

In a CMS I want to set videos as background in a DIV. For this I use the following 3 jquery-lines:

```
1. $(top.activeBaseElement).css('background-image', 'url(' + obj_backgroundImage + ')');
2. $(top.activeBaseElement).addClass('fcontent-video-bg');
3. $(top.activeBaseElement).prepend(' <video class="vid-bg-cont" loop muted autoplay poster="..."><source src="' + obj_backgroundImage + '" type="video/mp4"></video>' );
```

**top.activeBaseElement** is the DIV-Container which should get the BG-video:

```
<div class="fcontent fcontent-video-bg" ...>
  <video loop muted autoplay poster="...">
    <source src="..." type="video/mp4">
  </video>
...
```

Line 1 writes the video as a background image only for the preallocation/display in the corresponding dialog.
Line 2 adds a class for a few styles, line 3 adds the video container inside the DIV.
Works great!

To remove the video again, I use these 3 lines:

```
1. $(top.activeBaseElement).css('background-image', '');
2. $(top.activeBaseElement).removeClass('fcontent-video-bg');
3. $(top.activeBaseElement + ' > video').remove();
```

Line 3 results in the following error: *Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] > video*

Seems that video is not supported as element by DOM remove???

I also tried `$(top.activeBaseElement + ' > .vid-bg-cont').remove();` or only `$('.vid-bg-cont').remove();`

Nothing works...

How the hell do I get rid of the video element again?
I am desperate and find nothing
Thanks and nice regards

Comment: Can you just call `$(top.activeBaseElement).empty()`?

Comment: Yes, this works - BUT: After the video element there are other DIVs inside the fcontent-DIV and they disappear as well! I also can't enclose the video with another DIV, because the video should fill the whole fcontent-DIV as background...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't think it has anything to do with the video element itself.
I have now put a DIV around the video-element:

```
<div class="fcontent" ...>
  <div class="vid-bg-cont">
    <video ...>
      <source... />
    </video>
  </div>
  <div>
    ... regular content in fcontent
  </div>
  <div>
    ... still more regular content in fcontent
  </div>
</div>
```

`$(top.activeBaseElement + ' > .vid-bg-cont').remove();` does not work either (with error)

`$(top.activeBaseElement + ' > .vid-bg-cont').empty();` does not work (without error, but the content of vid-bg-cont is still there!)

`$(top.activeBaseElement).remove();` works and removes the complete fcontent-container and `$(top.activeBaseElement).empty();` works, too and clears the fcontent-container (this 2 only as a test)...

I think it is somehow due to the referencing - but I don't understand it...
(I'm using jquery2. I'm not sure that has anything to do with this. For compatibility reasons I cannot and do not want to update jquery (at the moment)...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is maybe because, you are trying to concatenate a jQuery object with a string. That is why it is giving an error.

Just replace the third line with this:

```js
$(top.activeBaseElement).children('.vid-bg-cont').remove();
```

Comment: Yes of course - that's it! JESUS CHRIST how stupid. Thanks a lot!!!